# Value from json object to var or String and slice it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I have this object:

```
data= {
       date_code: '',
       status_code: '',
       date_order: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_due: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_dispatch: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
};
```

And this function to perform submit data as json :

```
vm.onSubmit = function (data) {
            const dateOrder = data["date_order"];
            dateOrder = dateOrder.slice(0, 10);
            data["date_order"] = dateOrder;
            var json = JSON.stringify(data);
            $scope.table.jsonData = json;
};
```

I want to get the value of "date_order" and store it to var for slice the date.

How can I do that in angularjs?

Comment: is this what you mean? var date_order =data.date_order;

Comment: @bdalina: What's the purpose of `JSON.stringify` here?

Comment: Your example shows an object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
data= {
       date_code: '',
       status_code: '',
       date_order: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_due: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_dispatch: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
};

console.log(data.date_order);
var dateOrder = data.date_order;
var datePart = dateOrder.split("T")[0];
console.log(datePart);
```

After that you can assign it to the `$scope` like this:

```
$scope.table.jsonData = datePart;
```

Part which worked:

```
var dateOrder = data["date_order"];
date = dateOrder.split("T")[0];
data["date_order"] = date;
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
$scope.table.jsonData = json;
```

Comment: value is not stored in variable

Comment: @mauliksompura Even then also you can use it the same way shown above

Comment: it cannot slice the string

Comment: Why do you need to slice?

Comment: okey I edited question see the function..

Comment: I want only the date part to store it to the database

Comment: @mauliksompura Check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152816/discussion-between-mauliksompura-and-pritam-banerjee).

Answer (score 2):

Very simple - just use regular JS to grab it, angular is not a concern here.

```js
const data = {
       date_code: '',
       status_code: '',
       date_order: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_due: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
       date_dispatch: '2017-08-04T18:30:00.000Z',
};

const dateOrder = data["date_order"]

console.log(dateOrder)
```

Comment: Or you can use the dot notation provided there are no spaces and special characters except underscore. `var dateOrder = data.date_order`

Comment: I have to get it in the angular controller..